# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. when running g2p-seq2seq --version

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, pocketsphinx

mac OS
I am trying to use cmu dictionary for speech recognition.
Steps I took:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

pip3 show tensorflow
```

result:

> - Name: tensorflow
> - Version: 1.12.0
> - Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
> - Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
> - Author: Google Inc.
> - Author-email: opensource@google.com
> - License: Apache 2.0
> - Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> - Requires: protobuf, keras-preprocessing, tensorboard, termcolor, numpy, wheel, keras-applications, six, absl-py, grpcio, gast, astor
>     Required-by:

And then:

```
pip install tensor2tensor==1.5.0
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
g2p-seq2seq --version
```

Result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/g2p-seq2seq", line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('g2p-seq2seq==6.2.2a0', 'console_scripts', 'g2p-seq2seq')()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
>       return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
>       return ep.load()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2346, in load
>       return self.resolve()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2352, in resolve
>       module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2p_seq2seq-6.2.2a0-py2.7.egg/g2p_seq2seq/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from g2p_seq2seq import app
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2p_seq2seq-6.2.2a0-py2.7.egg/g2p_seq2seq/app.py", line 29, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: __Py_FalseStruct
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
>   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Inside pycharm IDE console,

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

gave me this:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7
>     return f(*args, **kwds)
>
> ---

Updated:

I go to this [github site](https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build) and download the correct wheel (python 3.7 for mac os 10.13).
And reinstall tensorflow by

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade /Users/cindy/Documents/pythonworkspace/sphinxenv/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl --user
```

I create a python file **tensorflow_test.py** with only one line:

```
imoprt tensorflow as tf
```

The console didn't throw out errors if I execute this file.

However

```
 g2p-seq2seq --version
```

now tells me

> ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Comment: You look to be installing g2dp-seq2seq in a different python installation and tensor flow in another. What is the output of running `$(pip3 -V)` in the terminal. Try setting the path to the site-packages folder returned in the output in your `PATH` and redo the g2p-seq2seq version command

Comment: Thank you! pip3 -V: pip 19.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7) my $PATH is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
 Now what should I do? thanks.

Comment: How I install g2p:`$sudo python3 setup.py install`

Comment: Did you already try installing the published version of `g2p-seq2seq` in [PyPI][https://pypi.org/project/g2p-seq2seq/] using `pip3`?

Comment: Now after I added this  **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/** to $PATH, the `g2p-seq2seq --version` now tells me that my tensorflow is too old. **This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 1.13.0; Detected an installation of version 1.12.0. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.**

Comment: Well the latest published version for [tensorflow on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) is at `1.12.0`. You can install `1.13.0` straight of  GitHub though https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Oluwafemi Sule says in comment is right.

```
pip3 -V
```

gives me

> pip 19.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

At the same time,

```
echo $PATH
```

gives me

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public

As Oluwafemi Sule recommends,
add

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages

to  **PATH** variable of Mac.

re-echo PATH again:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public

Now

```
g2p-seq2seq --version
```

no longer has the **ImportError: No module named tensorflow** error.

(However, I still need to solve the problem of tensorflow being too old.)